# Float is 0 after integer division

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgfloat

It might be a simple solution but I can not fix it.

I am dividing 2 integers :

```
finishedGameFinalScore = [score integerValue];
CGFloat interval = 2/finishedGameFinalScore;
NSLog(@"interval = %f",interval);
```

The log returns `0.000000`

Is there a limit for decimal places? I need to preserve the decimal result.

Thanks
Shani

Comment: `CGFloat finishedGameFinalScore = [score floatValue];` `CGFloat interval = 2.0f/finishedGameFinalScore;`

Comment: You have to divide by a floating pointer number to get a floating point number.

Comment: This is true for every C-based language.  Dividing two ints results in an int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS int always returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102750/ios-int-always-returning-0)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you're dividing an integer by another integer and then casting the result to a float.

So you have 2 (an integer) and some other number (also an integer). Then you divide 2 by this number - which is probably greater than 2. Let's say it's 3.

`Integer` sees 2/3 and he's like "0.66666667? Pshh, no one ever needs anything after the decimal point anyway". So he truncates it. You just have 0.

Then `Integer` gives the number to Mr. `float` and Mr `float` is super happy to get a number! He's all like "yay, a 0! I'm going to add ALL OF THE SIGNIFICANT DIGITS". And that's how you end up with 0.0000000.

So yeah, just cast to a float first. Or even a double!

[image]

Comment: Of even just do `CGFloat interval = 2.0/finishedGameFinalScore;` (add the `.0`). As `2.0` is a `CGFloat`, the result will be a `CGFloat` keeping all the decimals.

Answer (score 13):

@**Dustin** said u will need to **typecast** your **divider value to float** as it goes in float it shows integer value

**CASE 1: Typecast**

```
NSString *score = @"3";
 int interval = [str intValue];
 CGFloat interval = (2/(float)interval);
 NSLog(@"interval = %.2f",interval);
```

**CASE 2: No need for typecast**

```
NSString *score = @"3";
 float interval = [str floatValue];
 CGFloat interval = (2/interval);
 NSLog(@"interval = %.2f",interval);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add the f-hint to the number 2. in this case that will do the trick.

```
CGFloat interval = 2.0f/finishedGameFinalScore;
```

all the above/below answers are correct and fully explain why this work.

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't add this as a new answer if there are already two answers unless it adds significant important data. You could comment it on the question or another answer if you think it really adds something. But I'll +1 it because you're new.

Answer (score 1):

just devide long value from 1.0 and assigned to float variable.

```
unsigned long l1 = 65536;
unsigned long l2 = 256;
float f = (l1/1.0)/(l2/1.0);

NSLog(@"%f",f);
```