# iOS int always returning 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer, int

I am doing a small calculation but it always returns 0..

```
    int totalBothTeams = [prefs integerForKey:@"totalTimeBothTeams"];
    int someCalculation = (totalBetween / totalBothTeams) * 100;

    NSLog(@"Time: %i", someCalculation);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: integer division/truncation. try `(totalBetween * 100 / totalBothTeams)`

Comment: You really should have learned this sort of stuff when you learned C, and you should have learned C before diving into Objective-C.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that `totalBetween` is less than `totalBothTeams` - in which case the division

```
totalBetween / totalBothTeams
```

results in the integer value `0`

If you are looking for a "percentage" type of answer, you can multiply by 100 before taking the division. You will still get "rounding down". Or you can do the whole thing in double precision and cast at the end:

```
(totalBetween * 100) / totalBothTeams
```

or

```
(totalBetween * 100.0) / totalBothTeams + 0.5
```

- the latter will round correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here is what actually happening:

```
int someCalculation = (totalBetween / totalBothTeams) * 100;
```

In this, if `totalBothTeams > totalBetween`.. and by name it is..

`(totalBetween / totalBothTeams)` will return 0 as it is integer division.

and 0*any thing =0

so go for `(totalBetween * 100 / totalBothTeams);`