# NSLog float output 0.00000

Tags: objective-c, cgfloat

```
    NSLog(@"Number: %f", [self calculateScore]);

    - (CGFloat)calculateScore {
        CGFloat score;
        score = (_bestPossibleMove/_movesMade) * 5.0;
        return score;
    }
```

So I have 2 instance variables _bestPossibleMove and _movesMade.  The former is set to 6.0 from the start, and the latter will be 16.0 by the time the game is completed.  When I get to the NSLog message, calling [self calculateScore] keeps giving me 0.0000 when it should be giving me a number slightly smaller than 5.0 and greater than 0.0.  Any reason for this?

Comment: What are the data types for `_bestPossibleMove` and `_movesMade`?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint and checked if they are correct before NSLog?

Comment: @rmaddy is on to something: if the variables are int types the division will either be 0 or 1 (and that only when `_bestPossibleMove == _movesMade`), giving you a score of 0 or 5.

Comment: @fbrereto It's not just 0 or 1. It could be any integer value if both variables are integer types.

Comment: @rmaddy Yep, apologies: I had misinterpreted the code. Regardless, if the variables are both integer types the value will not be what OP expects.

Comment: _bestPossibleMoves and _movesMade are both CGFloats.  I have set _bestPossibleMoves set to 6.0 and _movesMade is incremented by int 1 every time I interact with this object that makes the _movesMade increase.

Comment: Could it be the [self calculateScore] portion?  self is (when you track it down) the motion of swiping as the receiver of the message (located in a move method).  I could put the NSLog call inside each 4 individual swipeLRDU methods (but I don't think that will make a difference)

Comment: Also, my apologies, _bestPossibleMove and _movesMade are properties

Comment: Try changing the `NSLog` to `NSLog(@"%f | %f | Number: %f", _bestPossibleMove, _movesMade, [self calculateScore]);` - or use the debugger. I'm guessing you won't see what you expect... HTH

Comment: I used _bestPossibleMove as a property.  How would I write it so I can set it to 6.0 and be able to retrieve that number?  Currently I'm reading 0.0000, everything else though reads as they're supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's answer can help you [Float is 0 after integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969264/float-is-0-after-integer-division)

so we just cast one to a float (_bestPossibleMove*1.0)

```
score = (_bestPossibleMove*1.0/_movesMade) * 5.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

when _bestPossibleMove's value is greater than _movesMade's value then /(devision) return 0.so it returns 0.00000.